# For loop using enumerate

Tags: python, enumerate

How to make the loop:

```
for i, line in enumerate(lines_f1, start = 0):
```

start counting from 1 (i = 1), and incrementing by 2 in each iteration?

Comment: Kinda depends on what programming language you're talking about.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to get? i = [1,3,5,7,...] and lines_f1[i]?

Answer (score 2):

Just take the regular enumeration (0, 1, 2, 3 etc), and use it to calculate the number you want:

```
>>> lines_f1 = ['line1', 'line2', 'line3', 'line4', 'line5']
>>> for i, line in enumerate(lines_f1, start = 0):
...     i = 1 + i*2
...     print i, line
...
1 line1
3 line2
5 line3
7 line4
9 line5
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want to start at 1, start at 1:

```
enumerate(lines_f1, start = 1)
```

If you want to skip every other line:

```
import itertools
for i,l in itertools.islice(enumerate(lines_f1, start = 1),0,None,2):
    pass #whatever you want here
```

If you just want to number with twice `i` in ieach iteration, just multiply:

```
for i,l in enumerate(lines_f1, start = 1):
    linenum = 2*i
```

Comment: That should actually be `start = 0` and `linenum = 1 + 2*i` (we want (1,3,5,7) not (2,4,6,8))

Comment: @nmclean (a) show me where that requirement is written (b) in any case, it is clear from this answer how one would achieve that

Comment: The question is worded ambiguously, but he did explicitly say *"start counting from 1 (i = 1)"*. In your sequence, `i` would never equal 1.

Comment: @nmclean Yes it would.

Comment: You have two sequences, each of which follow half of the requirements. One of them increments by 2 but does not start at 1, while the other starts at 1 but does not increment by 2.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your desired output is, but:

```
lines_f1 = ["a",'b','c','d','e','f']  
print range(1,len(lines_f1),2), lines_f1[1::2]
```

Yields:

```
 [1,3,5] ['b','d','f']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) functions to avoid building unnecessary separate lists.

When you say you want to "increment by 2", it's unclear whether you want to skip lines, or only increment `i`. If you want to skip lines, use Marcin's answer. Otherwise, try:

```
for i, line in itertools.izip(itertools.count(1, 2), lines_f1):
```

Comment: Multiplication would work just as well, and be clearer.

Comment: In Python 3.x it's just `zip` instead of `itertools.izip`.

Comment: @Marcin I posted that before I saw your edit. I think it's debatable which is clearer. Multiplication is more explicit, but most people think "count by 2 starting at 1" rather than in terms of math. Note you can also give the arguments explicitly like `count(start=1, step=2)`.